# Displaying overlapping points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, overlapping-features, visualisation

I am trying to produce a map of last years emergency responses in my area in 2018. I am entering a CSV file into QGIS which is working fine. The addresses and Lat and Long have been verified.

I have several locations that have had multiple emergencies in the last year and my problem is that the overlapping incidents are not showing up. Any suggestion?

Comment: What do you mean by "...not showing up."?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 28):

Try renderers: ["Point displacement"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#point-displacement-renderer) or ["Point Cluster"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#point-cluster-renderer) from symbology menu. (QGIS 3.x required for point cluster.)

[image]

As point displacement they can look like this for example:
[image]

And as point cluster like this for example:
[image]

Play around with the settings to fit your needs. You can combine these with graduated, categorized or rule based renderer; Set up own styles and adjust the distance they shall get merged within. As well as a lot of other possibilities.