# Creating map with no overlapping symbols using QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, symbology, overlapping-features

I've read responses like [Displaying overlapping points in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/308139) detailing the use of point cluster and point displacement in QGIS, but those methods only seem to work well when dealing with small clusters in an otherwise spaced out map.

This is a map of some of the points I'm working with:

[image: point map]

When I try using grid-based point displacement, the clusters overlap:

[image: point map with grid clusters]

Does anyone know of a good way to resolve this in QGIS, other than splitting up the dataset and using different methods for the denser areas?

Optimally, I'd like to have the points in clustered areas look like a grid tiled map, like [this one](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2Ftrevortombe%2Fstatus%2F1186665628523851776&psig=AOvVaw3NeaDxiKyInT1GCsqWFZGJ&ust=1632935908632000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAwQjhxqFwoTCODUqLmWovMCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAU), while maintaining the point locations for the less dense areas:

[image: Canada election grid tile map]

Comment: Please tell us a bit more about the kind of data you have and the goal of the visualization. Maybe a heatmap or point clustering with circles, scaled accordung to the number of points they represent,  would be better apt. See e.g. https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQFmwJKp-Jrn0-gpSi-hhD9xUcM2qjQWPhmng&usqp=CAU

Comment: @Babel I probably should have mentioned that these points will be color-coded based on different categories, so it's important to ensure that each point remains visible, and reasonably close to its actual location. That's why I didn't use a heatmap.

Comment: OK - so points that are close together do not belong to the same category and will not get the same color? So you'll have a wild mix of colors - many points one near the next with different colors? Not sure how easy such a map will be readable... Maybe consider a point cluster map with: 1) different colors for different categories, 2) varying size representing the number of points clustered per circle - something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkE3P.png