# Arrange geometry of points by attribute

Tags: qgis, address

I am working on a project where I am modelling data from an address book in QGIS. Every entry from the address book is represented by one point on the map. One of the attributes of the objects is the house number.

Is there a way to (semi)automatically move the points that share a house number closely together? So that it is possible to visually represent people living in the same house, like in the image attached.

[image]

Manually moving all the points is not an option, because there are too many.

Comment: Is Point Cluster layer style an option?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/308139/displaying-overlapping-points-in-qgis/308141

Answer (score 1):

You can use group by clause on the address column and calculate the average position like this:

```
SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(avg(ST_X(geom)), avg(ST_Y(geom))), 3857), address
FROM adresses GROUP BY address;
```

I supposed the name of the table is *addresses* and there is an *address* column.